# Basic/Elementary Geometry problem.

Tags: geometry

[image]

The problem is shown in the image. I'm not able to post images yet.. What are the next steps to to find how tall the triangle is?  So far i see, that the 3 triangles are similar; however, even by these similarities and by the fact that $AP^2+PB^2=100$ I'm unable to move forth.

Comment: ctrl + g and add your image. Preferentially write down your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: I need 10 rep to post pictures; thats what i meant.

Comment: I don't think this question has sufficient information. There is no reason why the height couldnt be infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is impossible.

Suppose that there exist such points.

Let $\alpha=\angle{PAB},\beta=\angle{PBA}$. And let $C$ be the third point of the triangle.

Then, from $\triangle{PAB}$, we have $$\alpha+\beta=90^\circ.$$

Now we have 
$$\angle{ACB}=180^\circ-\angle{CAB}-\angle{CBA}=180^\circ-2(\alpha+\beta)=0^\circ,$$ which contradicts that the three points $A,B,C$ form a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

The angles in the figure are not drawn to proper angular proportion. BY is not convincing as  a bisector of $XBA$.

Anyway, we can even verbally show its error.

If $ PAB + PBA$ is 90 degrees, due to bisections given the double angles sum

$YAB + XBA$ must be 180 degrees.

It makes AY parallel to BX by virtue Euclid's very early theorems on parallelism.

AY is parallel to BX and so C is of infinite height or distance from AB.
[image: Correct Construction]